Do authors publish how they calculate/results of their reliability tests?
I am in political science.
I was a research assistant and contributed to a project as a coder, but not much else. I wasn't too impressed with the project, I coded stuff but there was no way this would have any reliability.
The project was eventually published in a highly regarded journal and the Krippendorff's Alpha is very high, like 0.85+ high, which seems unlikely to me. I am just wondering, do the editors/peer reviewers ask how is this stuff calculated or just take the results in the face value?
Or can I contact the journal to ask them, because there is no way what I coded and what the other person did has that level of agreement.

There is no universal here. Some reviewers are more diligent than others. Some authors are more forthcoming than others. Don't try to generalize too much from one paper.

I don’t understand the situation. It looks like you are an author of a published paper ("the results are out on a highly regarded journal"). So you should know whether you published how the results were calculated and if the editor/reviewer asked for it. I especially don’t see why you would want to actively approach the journal about this.

@MisterMiyagi I was not an author. I was an assistant in project X and worked at project Y as a second coder. Just that. Did not write anything, just received the "training" and went on coding, and sent the results. During that time, I became familiar with the project and realised that the whole structure was problematic scientifically. However, I thought well, this would be reflected in results but results look amazing, especially the reliability and validity, so high. Hence my curiosity, how they share it or do journals expect the process to be shared? Or do they just report the number?

Editors and peer reviewers do not have the capacity to judge every calculation in a paper. Their role is typically to judge things at a higher level; did you ask a good question, did you select the appropriate variables to include in the model?
Scientific publishing is still built on a lot of trust that authors are not lying or making things up.
Each journal sets its own standards for what sort of data and code should be shared. The paper may have a statement to the effect of "Data are available (in the Supplementary Material/on Zenodo)." If it doesn't, the data are not publicly accessible. I am not in political science, but I get the sense that they are lagging behind in data- and code-sharing this way.
It seems like you haven't seen your co-rater's codes. That's fine, of course, but consider that you and them may have been more reliable than you realized. I have sat through many presentations and remember thinking "I'm surprised that's as reliable as it is."
Do not approach the journal unless you have solid evidence of falsification, i.e., you got the data from the project, and calculated reliability yourself.


Yes, editors/peer reviewers ask how this stuff is calculated.

You should not contact the editor or the journal. If you have serious doubts, you should express them clearly to the authors and suggest that x result is unreliable for y and z.

Forget it otherwise.



okay, so the authors submitted some sort of code alignment csv or something when submitting their article?

It depends on the journal. Some journals have specific guidelines requiring the authors to submit data and replication code; others don't. Some referees will check this; some will not.
